# Expanding FEH capabilities to preview RAW files

Tags: files, scripting, images, feh

I would like to preview RAW files in FEH. I now I can do the following

```
nufraw-batch --embedded-image DSC_0151.NEF --output=- | feh -
```

which opens the image in feh, but only works on one image at a time.

I tried

```
 nufraw-batch --embedded-image * --output=- | feh -
```

but I get an error.

I would like to achieve a command that works exactly like `feh` when launched in a directory, opening up the first image and letting me scroll through all of them.

Comment: The kneejerk solution here would be to loop through the images and call `nufraw-batch` on each one in succession, but that would end up calling `feh` multiple times, which may not be what you want. Does `feh` let you "scroll through all of them" if you provide multiple files to it on the commandline? One could then write some temporary files, call `feh` on them, and clean up afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`feh` has builtin way to process raw files. The feature is implemented via external `dcraw` tool. Ensure it is installed in your system and follow instruction from `man feh`:

```
SUPPORTED FORMATS
<..>
If dcraw is available, feh also supports RAW files provided by cameras and will 
display the embedded thumbnails. Use --conversion-timeout timeout with a 
non-negative value to enable support for these formats.
```